# If $E=\{1/n:n\in\Bbb{N} \}$ and $f(x)= 1,x\in E,\;f(x)=0,x\notin E $, then show that $f$ is integrable and to compute $\int^{1}_{0}f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E=\{1/n:n\in\Bbb{N} \}$ and define a function $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ by
\begin{align}  f(x)=\begin{cases} 1,&x\in E\\0,&x\notin E .\end{cases} \end{align}
I want to show that $f$ is integrable and to compute $\int^{1}_{0}f(x)dx$.

**Proof of integrability.**

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $x\in E$. Then, there exists $N$ such that $x=\frac{1}{N}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ 
Consider a partition $P=\{x_0,x_1,\cdots,x_k\}$ of $[0,1]$ such that 
$$\frac{1}{N}=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_k=1.$$
Take a refinement, $P_0=\{0,1/N\}\cup P:=\{t_0,t_1,\cdots,t_m\}$ such that $t_m-t_2<\frac{1}{N^2}$.

\begin{align} U(f,P_0)-L(f,P_0)&=\sum^{m}_{j=1}(M_j-m_j)\Delta t_j \\&=\sum^{m}_{j=1}M_j\Delta t_j \\&=M_1\Delta t_1+\sum^{m}_{j=2}M_j\Delta t_j\\&\leq 1\cdot\frac{1}{N}+N\sum^{m}_{j=2}\Delta t_j\\&< 1\cdot\frac{1}{N}+N\cdot\frac{1}{N^2} \\&< \frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}\\&=\epsilon \end{align}
Hence, $f$ is integrable. So, there a simple way I can compute $\int^{1}_{0}f(x)dx$?

Comment: Your proof seems to reuse "$n$" 2-3 different ways.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks! I've edited it.

Comment: In what sense did you edit?  The first line still says $x = 1/n, n \in \mathbb{N}$, I assume that means "$x = 1/n$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$." But your next line starts talking about "for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$."  You need to clarify if you are using a _particular_ $n$ that is fixed throughout, or not. (equivalently, is $x$ fixed throughout, or not).

Comment: @Michael: Okay, let me do that.

Comment: Your function is quite similar to the [Dirichlet Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nowhere_continuous_function#Dirichlet_function). In particular, though, your function is only $1$ at rational points of the form $1/n$ while Dirichlet's function is $1$ at all rational points. However, like with Dirichlet's function, and other similar functions like [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function), the function is Riemann integrable, with the integral result being $0$ over any range, just like Greg Martin's answer states for your case.

Comment: @JohnOmielan The Dirichlet function isn't Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for pointing this out and my apologies for the mistake. I know the ruler function, a special case of Thomae's function, is Riemann integrable. I didn't think carefully enough about Dirichlet's function being $1$ at all those rational points, rather than a set of decreasing values, would mean it's not Riemann integrable.

Comment: I observe that YuiTo edited the first paragraph to make it easier to read .  Nevertheless the first sentence is still incorrect. If we start with the first sentence "Let $\epsilon>0$ and $x \in E$" then we have fixed those values $\epsilon$ and $x$, so we certainly cannot guarantee the second sentence "Then, there exists $N$ such that $x=1/N<\epsilon/2$." Minor (but important) modifications could fix this to make it precise and clear.

Answer (score 1):

You proved that $0 \le U(f,P_0)-L(f,P_0)<\varepsilon$ whenever $P_0$ is a partition that is sufficiently fine in terms of $\varepsilon$. But it's easy to see that $L(f,P_0) = 0$ for this function. So you really have proved that $0 \le U(f,P_0) < \varepsilon$, which is enough to conclude that the integral equals $0$.